# jQuery click event not triggering for a list of buttons with same name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

These two are the buttons that appear several times and don't work:

```
    <button name='btnEditar' class='btn btn-outline-success me-4' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#staticBackdrop'><i class='bi bi-pencil-square'></i></button>
    <button name='btnEliminar' class='btn btn-outline-danger ms-4' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#staticBackdrop'><i class='bi bi-trash3'></i></button>
```

This one works fine (only one button):

```
    <button id="btnAgregar" type="button" class="btn btn-success px-4" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
        Agregar
    </button>
```

This is the JS code:

```
jQuery('#btnAgregar').on('click', function () {
    document.getElementById("staticBackdropLabel").innerHTML = "Agregar obra social";
});

jQuery("button[name='btnEditar']").on('click', function () {
    document.getElementById("staticBackdropLabel").innerHTML = "Editar obra social";
});

jQuery("button[name='btnEliminar']").on('click', function () {
    document.getElementById("staticBackdropLabel").innerHTML = "Eliminar obra social";
});
```

IDK why, but if I add this, the code works fine:

```
alert(document.getElementsByName("btnEditar"));
```

It's like if the alert function makes the click event works.

Comment: The universe is trying to tell you to stop using bloatware-jquery for simple tasks like this. Anyway, your code works fine in my test.

Comment: Code seems fine to me but why not utilize $("element").text("text here"); if your gonna use jquery. I dont like the idea mixing vanilla with jquery nothing wrong with it but just doesn't look right

Comment: I've already tried  $("element").text("text here"); and also didn't work. That's why I thought with vanilla it could work, but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding the onclick action like this:

```
<button class='btn btn-outline-success me-4' onclick='modalEdit()' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#staticBackdrop'><i class='bi bi-pencil-square'></i></button>
```

JS code:

```
function modalEdit() {
    $("#staticBackdropLabel").text("Editar obra social");
}
```